# Dividing a disc into equal parts

Tags: geometry

> Prove that it is not possible to divide a disc into $7$ parts of equal area by means of three straight lines.

Background: I saw this question asked in a way which seemed to imply the possibility of a simple solution.  The hint was given: what is the area on each side of a line?  Well, obviously, $\frac37$ and $\frac47$ of the whole area, but I can't see where that gets me.  Am I missing something really simple?

I tried doing some trig but it's a pain.  Even "obvious" things seem difficult to prove rigorously, for example, that the lines intersect each other at $60^\circ$ angles.

Note that the division is possible if the disc is replaced by a (suitable) different shape.  Therefore we must actually use the fact that the shape is a disc.  (Or perhaps just the fact that it is convex?)

Any ideas?  No lengthy trigonometric solutions please, I'm sure I could do that myself if I could be bothered to spend more time on it.

Please note that I am not asking for a ruler and compass construction, so [this question and answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440825/is-it-possible-to-divide-a-circle-into-7-equal-pizza-slices-using-geometric) is not relevant.

Comment: I think you may simplify this to `it is not possible to divide a disc into 7 parts` remove `equal area`!

Comment: @chouaib It is in fact easy to see you can divide a disc into 7 parts.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE go ahead, show me (by a simple drawing) only

Comment: @chouaib: draw a triangle inside a disc so that none of its vertices lie on the circle. Then extend the lines.

Comment: @Clayton, GREAT!! that's the only way I could divide the disc into 7 parts me too. Now my question: isnt't it better to start proving from this point? take any two regions and prove they're not equal is a lot easier way to tackle this problem, right ?

Comment: Appears convexity suffices; this could lead to an easier proof.

Comment: Meanwhile, the 3/7 business cuts down the configuration space to, in effect, dimension two. Each line is a fixed distance from the origin. Fix one. The other two are given entirely by two relative angles.

Answer (score 2):

Each line splits the disk into parts of areas $3/7 A$ and $4/7 A$, where $A$ is the area of the disk, and that determines the distance $d$ from the centre of the disk to the line.  The general arrangement has to be something like

[image]

where the intersection of two lines is in the $4/7 A$ region for the other line.
In order for the three wedge-shaped regions to have the same areas, the angles between each pair of lines has to be the same (so $\pi/3$).
That should be enough information to determine the area of the central triangle, say.
If it's not $1/7 A$, you're done.

Comment: Yes. For circle of radius 1, the distance of each line from the origin is $\delta \approx 0.112437096,$ the minimum area of the inner triangle is $\delta \sqrt{27} \approx 0.584240288,$ but $\pi/7 \approx 0.448798951.$ Th possible areas for the inner triangle are $\delta (\tan \alpha + \tan \beta + \tan \gamma )$ constrained by $\alpha + \beta +  \gamma = \pi.$ Going to double check minimum vs. maximum for inner triangle.